# JWT cakephp auth not working in production

Tags: cakephp-3.0, production-environment, jwt, unauthorized

Hello I have trouble with ADmad/JwtAuth.Jwt authentication with Cakephp 3.x app on production server.

I have installed my Cakephp app in several dev envirorments and is working just as expected. My problema comes when I try to run it on a web hosting service. I have tried two already, obtaining the same 401 (Unauthorized) error on both of them (ehost and dreamhost)

Fort he setup I followed this tutorial: http://www.bravo-kernel.com/2015/04/how-to-add-jwt-authentication-to-a-cakephp-3-rest-api/

Like I said locally and on dev envirorments Works perfectly. So is there any other think the web hosting needs to make this tutorial work? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Resolve by adding the "sub" property.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.2

```
public function token()
{
    $user = $this->Auth->identify();

    if (!$user) {
        throw new UnauthorizedException('Invalid username or password');
    }

    $this->set([
        'success' => true,
        'data' => [
            'token' => $token = JWT::encode(
                [
                    'id' => $user['id'],
                    'sub' => $user['id'],
                    'exp' => time() + 604800,
                    'iat' => time()
                ],
                Security::salt()
            )
        ],
        '_serialize' => ['success', 'data']
    ]);
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue but I have sub in there already is there anything else you had to do to get it to work on production? Locally everything works fine.